# How to change text using an interval

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which uses an array of text to change the text inside the span:

```js
var texts = ["Hola", "Bonjour", "Hallo"];
var count = 0;

function changeText() {
  $("#example").text(texts[count]);
  count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 50px;">
  Say <span id="example">hello</span> :-)
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div id="show" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;">
test
</div>
```

This function loops through the array on an continuous loop. Is there a way to loop through the array once, and end with the original "Hello", and once on the "Hello", display the ":-)" at the end and also display the div with the id "show" at the end?

Comment: you need to use `clearInterval();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have completed the loop, clear the interval.

```js
var texts = ["Hola", "Bonjour", "Hallo", "Hello"];
var count = 0;

function changeText() {
  $("#example").text(texts[count]);
  count < 3 ? count++ : reset();
}

function reset(){
  clearInterval(interval);
  $("#example").text($("#example").text()+" :-)");
  $("#show").show();
}
var interval = setInterval(changeText, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 50px;">
  Say <span id="example">Hello</span>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div id="show" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="display: none;">
test shown at end
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Any idea on the smiley face and the div too? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clear a timer set with the `setInterval()` when loop count is 4 with `clearInterval()`

```js
var texts = ["Hola", "Bonjour", "Hallo", "hello"];
var count = 0;
var interval = "";
function changeText() {
  $("#example").text(texts[count]);
  count < 4 ? count++ : stopLoop();
}
interval = setInterval(changeText, 500);

function stopLoop() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 50px; ">
  Say <span id="example">hello</span> :-)
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Don't repeat yourself DRY

Answer (score 0):

Clear the interval and have the last text have the :)

```js
var texts = ["Hola", "Bonjour", "Hallo :-)"];
var count = 0;
var tId;
function changeText() {
  if (count >= 3) {
    clearInterval(tId);
    $("#show").show();
  }  
  else $("#example").text(texts[count]);
  count++;
}
tId = setInterval(changeText, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 50px;">
  Say <span id="example">hello</span>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div id="show" style="display: none;">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. I don't recommend using setInterval.
2. If you can use lodash, use the _.delay function. Otherwise use the setTimeout function. For simplicity sake, I will use the setTimeout function below.

```js
var texts = ["Hola", "Bonjour", "Hallo", "Hello :-)"];
var count = 0;

function changeText() {
    $("#example").text(texts[count]);
    if (count === (texts.length - 1)) {
        $("#show").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
        $("#show").css("display", "none");
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        count = (count < texts.length) ? count + 1 : 0;
        changeText();
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    changeText();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size: 50px;">
  Say <span id="example"></span>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
<div id="show" style="display: none;">
test
</div>
```

Comment: For simplicity's sake, load an extra library to not use the built-in setInterval??? And this is a wasteful amount and testing of code `if (count === (texts.length - 1)) {
        $("#show").css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
        $("#show").css("display", "none");
    }`

Comment: `$("#show").toggle(count === (texts.length - 1))` is in my mind more elegant if you do want to test every time around the loop

Comment: @mplungjan Well we can agree to disagree on whether to use setInterval. https://zetafleet.com/blog/2010/04/why-i-consider-setinterval-to-be-harmful.html

As for the if,else statement I keep it humanely readable given that this question is asked by a beginner. We can always optimize code but does it mean others (especially beginners) will understand?

Comment: This beginner seemingly uses ternary operators. Good idea to show them simplified use of jQuery rather than the CSS change you suggest